# Two loops from tables at different frequencies in lua

Tags: for-loop, lua, lua-table

I am building a loop that should use different frequencies for switching to the next value. An example:

```
local color = {"Blue", "Green", "Red"}
local group = {1, 2, 3}

for i=1.3 do
  cmd(string.format('group %i ; store color %q ; clearall', group[i], color[j]))
end
```

This should result in:

```
Group 1 Blue,
Group 1 Green,
Group 1 Red,
Group 2 Blue.......
```

I can't get the loop in the loop, since I can't let table group move up only once in 2 cycles. Also using double values or using [i] twice didn't seem to work.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Could you give the complete output expected?

Comment: Could you explain what does this phrase mean: "i can't let table group move up only once in 2 cycles"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the loop for nine iterations (that's the number of combinations that you are making), and use `math.floor` to compute indexes:

```
local color = {"Blue", "Green", "Red"}
local group = {1, 2, 3}
for i=0, #color*#color-1 do
    local g = math.floor(i/3)
    local c = i-3*g
    print(string.format('group %i ; store color %q ; clearall', group[g+1], color[c+1]))
end
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/uoIsS0)

Answer (score 1):

A Simpler Version

```
for i,v in pairs(group) do
for k,c in pairs(color) do
print("Group " .. v .. " " .. c)
end
end
```

Very simple, what it does is it iterates through the group array and color array at the same time and print out each value, everytime it iterates through the group array, it iterates over all the items in the color array, Lua has built in technique to merge strings, you don't need to use the string library :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way considering the difference between `' '` and `" "`

```
for i=1, #color do 
  for _, v in pairs(color) do
      print('group '..i..' ; store color "'..v..'" ; clearall')
  end
end
```